# Add New Item --> Resource File (.RESX) option missing in .net core project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and trying to add a resources(resx) file to a .net core 2.1 project (not asp.net core).

When I open the 'Add New Item' menu, I cannot find there an option of a resx file (however, when i try to add to an asp.net core project i do find this option).

Any idea what is causing it?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473315/visual-studio-cant-find-resource-file-in-list-of-items-to-add-to-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio : can't find "resource file" in list of items to add to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473315/visual-studio-cant-find-resource-file-in-list-of-items-to-add-to-project)