# Update to .NETStandard 2.0 and Localization

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, localization, .net-standard-2.0

I followed [these instructions](https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/) to upgrade my Xamarin.Forms project to .NETStandard 2.0. Now I added a new entry to my *.resx* file and get a compile error:

> error CS0117: 'AppResources' does not contain a definition for 'MyKey'

I think the *AppResources.Designer.cs* file is not updated anymore. The following things seems to be wrong:

- According to the instructions I should delete *AssemblyInfo.cs*, which I have done only for the PCL and not the indivdual projects (iOS, Droid). On the other side you should add `NeutralResourcesLanguage` to the *AssemblyInfo.cs* according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows). So should I have a *AssemblyInfo.cs* or not?
- <s>I cannot change the access modifier if I open *AppResources.resx* (works after manipulating *.csproj*)</s>
- I only have this code in my new *.csproj* of the PCL

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.resx">
          <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator </Generator>
      </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  ```
- In the detailed build logs I found this and I don't know what I should do with this

> 1>  Task "CreateCSharpManifestResourceName" skipped, due to false
>   condition; ('%(EmbeddedResource.ManifestResourceName)' == '' and
>   '%(EmbeddedResource.WithCulture)' == 'true' and
>   '%(EmbeddedResource.Type)' == 'Non-Resx') was evaluated as ('' == ''
>   and 'false' == 'true' and 'Resx' == 'Non-Resx'). 1>  Task
>   "CreateCSharpManifestResourceName" skipped, due to false condition;
>   ('%(EmbeddedResource.ManifestResourceName)' == '' and
>   '%(EmbeddedResource.WithCulture)' == 'true' and
>   '%(EmbeddedResource.Type)' == 'Non-Resx') was evaluated as ('' == ''
>   and 'true' == 'true' and 'Resx' == 'Non-Resx'). 1>  Task
>   "CreateCSharpManifestResourceName" skipped, due to false condition;
>   ('%(EmbeddedResource.ManifestResourceName)' == '' and
>   '%(EmbeddedResource.WithCulture)' == 'true' and
>   '%(EmbeddedResource.Type)' == 'Non-Resx') was evaluated as ('' == ''
>   and 'false' == 'true' and 'Non-Resx' == 'Non-Resx').

My best bet would be to manually edit the *.csproj* from the PCL project. In my old *.csproj* I had this:

```
<Compile Include="Common\Localization\AppResources.Designer.cs">
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>

<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Common\Localization\AppResources.de.resx">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Common\Localization\AppResources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

But I don't think I can adopt it one-to-one. I tried to [play with it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18162/resource-file-doesnt-update.html), but didn't had success:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.Designer.cs">
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.de.resx">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

How do I get my translation working again?

Comment: Are you trying to embed your resources files in shared code?

Comment: @Adlorem: The resources are in the Portable Class Library (PCL), which is shared with the other projects (OS specific ones: iOS, Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only thing that was needed is to set the *Custom Tool* option of `AppResources.resx` to **`PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`**. This results into the following *.csproj* code:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.Designer.cs">
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.de.resx">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.resx">
        <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

The *Access Modifier* for the individual key/value pairs of `AppResources.resx` now is `Public`. All other language resource files have the *Acces Modifier* of `No code generation`.

I also deleted the other `AssemblyInfo.cs` files as it seems that it works without them and without `NeutralResourcesLanguage` as opposed to [the sample in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows). Nevertheless, I set the *Assembly netural language* under *Package* in the project properties. Therefore the *.csproj* now contains an `<NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>` entry.

What I find odd is that you [can't add a *Resource* file in Visual Studio anymore ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473315/visual-studio-cant-find-resource-file-in-list-of-items-to-add-to-project)