# Cannot create resx file for i18n

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

Still spinning up on Xamarin.Forms and C#.

Did some research and everything is telling me that to create my externalized strings file, I just right click on the directory, click New Item... then click on Resource file. The problem is that my list looks vastly different than the lists I'm seeing in the tutorials and doesn't include a Resource file. Here's my list:

[image]

[image]

So I'm not sure what to click to get a resource file. There's evidently some special stuff about it because I tried creating an empty file and naming it that and it was confused.

How do I create these i18n resource files in Xamarin?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try looking under the different categories list on the left hand pane?

Comment: I did. The one I showed seemed to have all of them. The other categories seem to be subsets of that one.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875994/7432242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Deczaloth, I added the C# desktop applications workload and that made the resources file available. Yet another fail from Microsoft.

Comment: @Tomerikoo The linked answer does not contain the answer, nor the link in that link directly as it is outdated. I have provided a summarized answer that does not require digging or guessing, so this is not a duplicate answer.